# How to make iframe flows properly in <li> form element in Safari (for iphone and ipad)

Tags: css, forms, mobile-safari, z-index

I create a [Measurement form](http://chicerman.com/pages/suit-measurements). Everything is working fine, however, there the embedded youtube videos are not working properly in iphone and ipad (safari). It works perfectly fine in the safari browser in a mac. I spent over 3 days on this, googling and trying to fix it, but no success. I tried to use z-index, but that won't work either. I am suspecting some overstacking issue with the code, but just couldn't find where it is. The code for html and css are below - there are also some JS codes, but i don't think that is the issue here and didn't attach. Any comments/insights would be really appreciated!

Html:

```
    <ol class="fs-fields">
        <li>
        <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="1. Name">What's your name?</label>
        <input class="fs-anim-lower" id="1. Name" name="1. Name" type="text" placeholder="ChicerMan" required/>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="2. Email" data-info="We won't send you spam, we promise...">What's your email address?</label>
        <input class="fs-anim-lower" id="2. Email" name="2. Email" type="email" placeholder="hello@chicerman.com" required/>
        </li>

        <li>....more codes...

        <li>
        <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="5. Neck Size">What's the size of your neck?</label>
        <input class="fs-anim-lower" id="5. Neck Size" name="5. Neck Size" type="text" placeholder="16 inches" />
        <br>
        <div class='embed-container fs-anim-upper'><iframe src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/5rPusisCojM?rel=0' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
        </li>

        <li>
        <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="6. Shoulder Width">How big are your shoulders?</label>
        <input class="fs-anim-lower" id="6. Shoulder Width" name="6. Shoulder Width" type="text" placeholder="21 inches" />
        <br>
        <div class='embed-container fs-anim-lower'><iframe src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/fkMZmphTTJo?rel=0' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
        </li>
```

Css:

```
.embed-container { 
  position: relative; 
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; 
  height: 0; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  max-width: 100%; 
} 

.embed-container iframe, 
.embed-container object, 
.embed-container embed { 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; left: 0; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
}

/* Switch view animation (we hide the current view, switch the view class and show it again) */
.fs-form.fs-show {
    -webkit-animation: animFadeIn 0.5s;
    animation: animFadeIn 0.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animFadeIn {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes animFadeIn {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}

.fs-form.fs-show .fs-fields {
    -webkit-animation: animMove 0.5s;
    animation: animMove 0.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animMove {
    from { top: 100px; }
}

@keyframes animMove {
    from { top: 100px; }
} /* we need to use top here because otherwise all our fixed elements will become absolute */

/* Animation classes & animations */
.fs-form li.fs-current {
    visibility: visible;
}

.fs-form li.fs-hide,
.fs-form li.fs-show {
    pointer-events: none;
}

/* Hide current li when navigating to next question */
.fs-form .fs-display-next .fs-hide {
    visibility: visible;
}

.fs-form .fs-display-next .fs-hide .fs-anim-lower,
.fs-form .fs-display-next .fs-hide .fs-anim-upper {
    -webkit-animation: animHideNext 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1) forwards;
    animation: animHideNext 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1) forwards;
}

.fs-form .fs-display-next .fs-hide .fs-anim-lower {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
    animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animHideNext {
    to { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-500px,0); }
}

@keyframes animHideNext {
    to { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-500px,0); transform: translate3d(0,-500px,0); }
}

/* Show new li when navigating to next question */
.fs-form .fs-display-next .fs-show .fs-anim-lower,
.fs-form .fs-display-next .fs-show .fs-anim-upper {
    -webkit-animation: animShowNext 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1) both 0.15s;
    animation: animShowNext 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1) both 0.15s;
}

.fs-form .fs-display-next .fs-show .fs-anim-lower {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.25s;
    animation-delay: 0.25s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animShowNext {
    from { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,500px,0); }
}

@keyframes animShowNext {
    from { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,500px,0); transform: translate3d(0,500px,0); }
}

/* Remove IE clear cross */
input[type=text]::-ms-clear {
    display: none;
}


/* Adjust form for smaller screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 52.5em) {
.fs-fields {
    position: relative;
}

.fs-fields > li {
    position: absolute;
}

    body {
        min-height: 500px;
    }

    .fs-form-wrap {
        font-size: 65%;
    }

    .fs-form {
        top: 6em;
        right: 2em;
        left: 0;
        padding: 0 3.75em 0 1em;
        width: auto;
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }
}
```